# ssmtp settings for namecheap: Invalid response SMTP Server (STARTTLS)

Tags: linux, smtp, starttls, ssmtp, namecheap

I am trying to configure ssmtp to use the namecheap smtp server to send emails. My current configuration:

```
root=my@email.com
mailhub=mail.privateemail.com:465
rewriteDomain=email.com
hostname=email.com
AuthUser=my@email.com
AuthPass=password
FromLineOverride=YES
UseTLS=NO
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

Trying to send a test email using `cat - | sudo /usr/sbin/ssmtp -vvvv my@email.com` results in the following output in my syslog:

```
Jun 17 13:55:08 hostname sSMTP[12161]: Creating SSL connection to host
Jun 17 13:55:18 hostname sSMTP[12161]: Invalid response SMTP Server (STARTTLS)
Jun 17 13:55:18 hostname sSMTP[12161]: Cannot open mail.privateemail.com:465
```

So far, no configuration change has had any impact. I find mostly solutions for gmail, which do not work for Namecheap it seems. The Namecheap documentation does not mention any special settings one needs to apply.

I tried setting it up with gmail and it worked flawlessly. I guess this means that my settings for the NameCheap SMTP are wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSMTP is expected to be TLS from the start.   This should work if you set UseTLS to Yes.  This port/protocol has been obsoleted now that the STARTTLS option is available.

If you want to use STARTTLS try the submission port (587).  I have verified that the submission port is open.

Comment: It worked. I wonder how you came up with using this (undocumented) port? I am asking because I'd like to be able to troubleshoot such issues on my own in the future!

Comment: Use of the submission port is standard for authenticated connections.  It is documented in the Message Submission RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6409.  Port 465 for SSMTP is deprecated see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS.